# recording video from a service with Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera2

I have issues on some phones that I can't test on (that's the first problem)
I'm trying to build a service that can record from camera2 API. But when I send the app to the background, on some phone it appears to have issues that I am failing to solve at the moment. I only have logs and cannot figure out the main reason for the app not working.

Thank you for helping

## Edit:

You'll find the actual source code that solved my problem here: https://bitbucket.org/dreamappsfr/kinghul

This was a POC that has been stopped. I honestly don't remember how I overcome this specifical issue at that time.

Comment: I think you can not access to camera in background service. You should bring your service to foreground using foreground notification.

Comment: In fact recording in service works for all devices, but when you send the app to the background, some apps just failed to restart a record. And according to the logs, it seems there is something somewhere that mess up with the media recorder state.

Comment: Which version android do you use? android 8 ? If you use android 8 add a foreground notification to your service. Here is an example : https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/6211176

Comment: I have a foreground notification already. It is supposed to work from API 21. And the issue has been reproduced on a Huawei P9 and a Samsung GS6. I cannot debug on these phones.

Comment: You cannot rely on a TextureView when your app is in background. I am not surprised that some devices keep it longer than others. Also, I believe that the log you posted comes from a *legacy* device not by coincidence: the backwards compatibility code in camera2 may be more vulnerable to surface being ripped away from it.

Comment: @AlexCohn Ok so what are the solution I have? What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you. Please understand that you sail uncharted waters. While running camera from background service is not explicitly forbidden by Google, it is not a supported scenario. This means that any solution you have today, may fail on a new device, or after system upgrade. This also means that, if you plan to distribute your app on Play Store, you need an efficient procedure of blacklisting devices that cause troubles. I hope you can find workarounds for P9 and S9, but I doubt you can do that without debug access to these devices.

Comment: You're going to need to share your MainActivity as it seems to be pointing to that file for trying to stop it, when it hasn't resumed.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: I manage to solve each problem I found by going back to Camera1 API. I was highly inspired by looking at stuff like this:
https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/c747398a8f0d5c8ec7be2c66522a80b43dfc9a1e/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah yep, but this is not within a service. And this is the whole complexity here :)

Comment: @Astyan did you get any solution?

Comment: Your links are dead, please update links.

Comment: @PratikButani You'll find my contribution on the edit part. Please, be aware that I did not update this for a long time and I don't plan to maintain it either.

Answer (score 2):

You would try with:

[Camera2-Video](https://github.com/WesleyElliott/Camera2-Video)

Basically it is a wrapper for the video capture using `Camera2`.

Add you your `build.gradle` file:

`compile 'com.wesleyelliott:camera2-video:0.0.2'`

and create a `Fragment` extended from `com.wesley.camera2.fragment.Camera2Fragment` and override the methods `getTextureResource` and `getVideoFile`.

To start recording, you must use the method: `startRecordingVideo()`, to stop it `stopRecordingVideo` and  to check if the app is currently recording a video or not, a method `isRecording()`.

I already used it and is the simpler way to record a video with `Camera2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but since I need to have the recording in a Service, I could not use this API.

Comment: So where is use of service as question asked for `video recording using service`?